# in django html detail template why did .all work, but .all() give an error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, jinja2

In my html file the following causes an error - error states Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'project.expenses.all()':

```
{% for expense in project.expenses.all() %}
  <h1>{{ expense.title}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

When I use the following code instead everything works well:

```
{% for expense in project.expenses.all %}
  <h1>{{ expense.title}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

If it helps with answering this, here is my models.py file:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    budget = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Category(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Expense(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expenses')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is the views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Project


#Create your views here.
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    slug_url_kwarg = "project_slug"
    template_name = 'budget/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = "project"
```

Comment: Because in Django templates, a variable does not contain parenthesis, but if the item is callable, the template will call it.

Comment: It looks like you are *not* using Jinja, but Django templates.

Comment: Oh I though Jinja was the templating language for django, did not know there was a difference. I was modifying from a tutorial where the guy was using function views not class views. Within the views.py  detail funciton view context he passed project.expenses.all(). Didn't realize you could not do that in the actual html

Comment: by default the Django template engine is used, which is *deliberately* restricted, Jinja is another template engine that aims to make templates more "useful", although there are good reasons to restrict this, since then people tend to write more business logic in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates have a special syntax. This is partly done to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the templates. For example it is not straightforward to call a function with arguments. One can use all sorts of "*tricks*" to do this, like custom template tags, custom template filters, etc. But the idea is to discourage that, and move such logic to the view itself.

If you write a variable, then Django will resolve that variable by looking if there is an variable with that name in the context, and for a sequence with dots, it will look for attributes, elements, etc. with that name to resolve the "chain".

If one of these elements is callable, the Django template engine will call these, as is written in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables):

> If a variable resolves to a **callable**, the template system will **call it with no arguments** and use its result instead of the callable.

[Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables), another template engine, however allows one to write Python-style expressions. For example, in Jinja, one can write:

```
<!-- Not in Django templates, but in Jinja templates -->
{{ foo.bar(qux) }}
```